# Renaming a pylons controller

Tags: python, pylons

Is there an automatic way I can use to rename a pylons controller? If I have to rename the controller manually which all files and filenames do I have to change. Thank you much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename the file containing the controller, as well as the name of the controller class itself within the file. As far as I know there is no automatic way to do this, although if you have many controllers to rename it might be worth the time to write a special script to do it for you.

As discussed on the [pylons-discuss](http://www.mail-archive.com/pylons-discuss@googlegroups.com/msg02923.html) group, it would be nice if the class within the controller file was generic, so it did not also have to be changed:

```
controllers/__init__.py
controllers/foo.py:
    class Controller...
controllers/bar.py:
    class Controller...
```

Comment: Thanks! Just another note for newbies like me, PLEASE REMEMBER TO CHANGE THE REFERENCES TO THE CONTROLLER FOR YOUR "TEMPLATES" AND "ROUTES".

Comment: Also the functional tests for the controller.